# My fail method in spout class is only working for first bolt, from second bolt onward its not working.

Tags: java, apache-storm

[image]

Note:
Bolt1 contains a list of first three prime number(2,3,5).
Bolt2 contains a list of second three set of prime number(7,11,13).
In Bolt3 it just check the number is prime or not.
From first bolt, i am able to call Fail() from spout class but from second bolt onward i am not able to call Fail() from spout class.

Topology class:

```
        ......
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("spout", new SpoutClass(), 1);
        builder.setBolt("bolt1", new Bolt1(), 1).shuffleGrouping("spout");
        builder.setBolt("bolt2", new Bolt2(), 1).shuffleGrouping("bolt1");
        builder.setBolt("bolt3", new Bolt3(), 1).shuffleGrouping("bolt2");
```

Spout class:

```
SpoutClass implements IRichSpout{
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private TopologyContext context;

    public void open(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        this.context = context;
        this.collector = collector;
        }

    public void nextTuple() {
        try {
            //messageQueue is blocking queue which contains data 
            String msg = messageQueue.take();
            String ackId = msg;
            this.collector.emit(new Values(msg), ackId);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void ack(Object msgId) {

        System.out.println("Acknowledges that this tuple has been processed ........... " + msgId);

    }

    public void fail(Object msgId) {

        System.out.println("FAILED To Process Message :-" + msgId);

    }
}
```

Bolt1 class:

```
public class Bolt1 extends BaseRichBolt {
private OutputCollector collector;
ArrayList<Integer> firstthreePrime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        firstthreePrime.add(2);
        firstthreePrime.add(3);
        firstthreePrime.add(5);
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
    }
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

        String message = (String) tuple.getValueByField("msg");

        System.out.println("Received " + message + " in Bolt1.");
        Integer number = Integer.valueOf(message);
        if (check this number contains bolt1 or not) {
            //if number is contains
            System.out.println(" Number is prime ............." + number + " and Throw from Bolt1");
            this.collector.fail(tuple);
        } else {
            collector.emit(new Values(message));
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
    }
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("msg"));
    }
}
```

Bolt2 class:

```
public class Bolt2 extends BaseRichBolt {
private OutputCollector collector;
ArrayList<Integer> secondthreePrime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        secondthreePrime.add(7);
        secondthreePrime.add(11);
        secondthreePrime.add(13);
public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;

    }
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

        String message = (String) tuple.getValueByField("msg");

        System.out.println("Received " + message + " in Bolt2.");
        Integer number = Integer.valueOf(message);
        if (check this number contains bolt2 or not) {
            //if number is contains
            System.out.println(" Number is prime ............." + number + " and Throw from Bolt2");
            this.collector.fail(tuple);
        } else {
            collector.emit(new Values(message));
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
    }
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("msg"));
    }
}
```

Bolt3 class:

```
public class Bolt3 extends BaseRichBolt {
private OutputCollector collector;

public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;

    }
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {

        String message = (String) tuple.getValueByField("msg");

        System.out.println("Received " + message + " in Bolt3.");
        Integer number = Integer.valueOf(message);
        if (check this number is prime or not) {
            //if number is prime
            System.out.println(" Number is prime ............." + number + " and Throw from Bolt3");
            this.collector.fail(tuple);
        } else {
            collector.emit(new Values(message));
            collector.ack(tuple);
        }
    }
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using BaseRichBolt, don't you want to anchor your outgoing tuples?

```
_collector.emit(tuple, new Values(message));
```

If you don't anchor them then they have no link to the tuple which came from the spout. Check out the docs: [Guaranteeing Message Processing](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.0/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html)

Comment: In the spout class, we can't emit with tuple. It work after adding into the bolt class:                                                                                    
  collector.emit(tuple,new Values(message));

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo meant BaseRichBolt. If it fixed your problem please accept my answer.